# How to tell Mac OS Messages.app to go online from the command line?

Tags: command-line, macos, messages, automation

I observed that quite often some accounts on Messages.app (Mac OS Sierra) may become offline and I want to automate the reconnection when I connect to VPN.

So, the question is: what command line commands should I run in order to start Messages.app and restore connections. Note: Messages.app may already be opened but my account may be offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the command for terminal:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Messages" to log in'
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Tested and worked.